# Make Fail2ban parse latest logs generated monthly.

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, fail2ban

I have a log file generated monthly (e.g `messageApril2015.log`,`messageMay2015.log`). Can anyone tell me how to make fail2ban parse the latest log?  I have read somewhere about adding `%F%Y` but it didn't work.

```
[domain]
enabled  = true
filter   = domain
logpath  = /1/domain/log/message%F%Y.log  
maxretry = 3
port = http,https
bantime = 60
```

When restart, I was getting this error:

```
Starting fail2ban: ERROR  Failed during configuration: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%F%Y.*'
```

Comment: AFAIK the only pattern matching that works in a `logpath` directive appears to be wildcard matching : `logpath /1/domain/log/message*.log` and then maybe run a monthly batch job to compress old log files so those don't match (and you save some disk space )

Answer (score 0):

You could run a cron job to update a symlink to the log you want it to process and then restart fail2ban.  You'd point the logpath value at the symlink.